# css columns with white-space nowrap does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

When using css columns on a container, it is displayed as 2 columns in this case. I set it to auto to make it to feel the width and then break when needed.

To make all the characters on the same row I use nowrap. This is where the unexpected appears. Instead of a force breaking of the column, it overflows the next column.

- Is this a browser bug?
- Can it be fixed without js and fixed width?

```css
ul {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 400px;
  columns: auto 2;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A very long long long long long text</li>
  <li>A short text</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zb7qvdpz/

Comment: either you use `wrap` or the `ellipsis` (as suggested in the answer) or what exactly do you expect?

Comment: Wait, you mean you want the columns to have different widths, right? That won't work; columns can't do that. Use `inline-block`, `float`, `flex`, `grid`...

Comment: remove nowrap it will work. bcz everything wont fit in same line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `text-overflow: ellipsis` on `li` elements. Also in `columns: auto 2` first value should be column-count and second should be column-width but that also won't fix this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb7qvdpz/2/).

You could also use `Flexbox` instead [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zb7qvdpz/3/)

```css
ul {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 400px;
  columns: auto 2;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>A very long long long long long text</li>
<li>A short text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid overflowing, but also make sure your text doesn't wrap to more than one line:

***use this***

```
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP use this? This could potentially remove desirable content from view.

Comment: because he wants nowrap also